# Why does our code give a map.polly error when calculating the beta?

Tags: r, error-handling, return, mapping, beta

In order to calculate the beta of a mutual fund in a specific year. We are trying to run a regression on the excess return on the market compared to the (market rate - risk free rate). Our code is as follows:

```
Returns_Database <- CRSP_Database %>%
 select(Wficn, caldt, Excess_Return, mktrf)%>%
  nest(data = c("Excess_Return", "mktrf")) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(Excess_Return = , mktrf = ), data = .))) %>%
```

How come we keep getting the map.polly error, or what are we missing?

Comment: `lm(Excess_Return = , mktrf = )` is syntactic gibberish.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.